# Viewing tensorboard output from scrip that is running in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tensorboard

I have a piece of python code running in GCE that trains a simple keras model on some images. I also provided the tensorboard callback. Now I want to view the output of this tensorboard log. How do I go about this since the tensorboard log files are on GCE?

I run `tensorboard -logdir logs` and I get the output:

`TensorBoard 1.7.0 at http://instance_1:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Putting the address into the browser didn't work and I am wondering if it would be possible to view this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is expose the tensorboard port to the public and block the access on the firewall for only access with your IP.

For doing that you need to create a firewall rule for the instance that allows your public IP access to the TCP port 6006. You have a guide for adding firewall rules on GCP [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules).

Now execute the following command to expose the tensorboard port:

```
tensorboard --logdir --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006
```

You can ensure that the port is exposed using `$ netstat -plunt`.

Now go to `http://$PUBLIC_IP_OF_instance_1:6006` .

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to open 
`http://$PUBLIC_IP_OF_instance_1:6006` from inside a VM? So instead of having to run `gcloud compute instances describe instance-name --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'` and copy+pasting the output and adding :6006, I could create a function that opens that link on my local machine. Probably not possible but asking out of interest.